# DJI Mobile UXSDK 4.8.1 issue with Mapbox SDK

Tags: dji-sdk

The Gradle of my android application has the following versions of libraries

**DJI Mobile UXSDK version: 4.7**

**Mapbox Version :4.2.1**

App works fine with the above version of libraries.

When I try to upgrade the **DJI UXSDK to 4.8.1** , its making me to force upgrade Mapbox SDK to latest versions (where many attributes and functions have been changed). Why is it necessary to upgrade the Mapbox SDK ?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think DJI MSDK have upgraded Mapbox UXSDK to 5.5.1, that's why it is asking me to force upgrade Mapbox SDK.